# How to upload downloadable documents on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

This question may sound silly and childish but still..
I am creating a blog where I will write articles and post some other stuff. There will be PDF's, eBooks, Office documents to download.

How do I create downloadable links like suppose if domain name is domain.com and document is test.pdf and the article is on domain.com/first-post then I require something like this:
domain.com/first-post/test.pdf where the person can read or download.

Any idea how to do this?

It is a self hosted Wordpress Blog.

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can **upload** the file **anywhere on your server** and just add a **direct link** on the article page. For example:

- Your post or article is located at `http://domain.com/first-post/`
- You **upload a PDF file named `test.pdf`** to a folder called `uploads` on your server `public_html` directory
- You can then add a the direct link `http://domain.com/uploads/test.pdf` anywhere on the page `http://domain.com/first-post/`
- You **label the link** "download the PDF" or *something similar* to **let the user know**
- **clicking** the link will mean **automatic download request** in *most cases* / **viewing** of the pdf file in a **new tab** in the rest.

2 - If by "*self hosted*" you mean that your **website is hosted on a local machine** in your **home / office** I would highly **advise against** hosting self-hosting any files. Use services like *Google Drive* or *Dropbox*, **they are free.**

Answer (score 0):

When editing a post click on add media button on the top editing bar then select a picture (or file) to upload. This will insert a file link in your post and clicking it will automatically download the file or in case of PDF it will view it online.